# How do I include hyperlink in XML with DTD

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, dtd

I am trying to move a hyperlink from  "author" element to "title" element. I cannot figure out how to make this XML valid with the below external dtd.

Currently, when validating, I receive this error:

> line 57   A ')' is required in the declaration of element type "frontmatter".

Originally the XML file had a hyperlink to a different URL in element author

Here is DTD:

```
<!--
Filename: book.dtd
Created by S. Renko All rights reserved.
-->

<!-- Begin of DTD -->
<!ENTITY % pname "(firstname, middlename?, lastname, (html:a)?)">
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT middlename (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT html:a ANY>
<!ATTLIST html:a 
        href CDATA #IMPLIED
        target CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ENTITY % frontmatter "(html:img?, html:a?, titlepage*, tableofcontents?, listoffigures?, preface*, foreword*, 
    dedication*, acknowledgment*, errata*, frontispiece*)">

<!ELEMENT html:img  EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST html:img 
        src CDATA #IMPLIED
        style CDATA #IMPLIED
        alt CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ENTITY % titleinfo "(title | subtitle | author | translator | date | note)*">
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST title class CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA) >

<!ELEMENT author %pname;>

<!ELEMENT book (metadata, frontmatter, body, end)>
<!ATTLIST book 
    xmlns CDATA #FIXED "http://www.steverenko.hostfree.pw/729/"
    xmlns:html CDATA #FIXED "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 

<!ELEMENT metadata (dc:title | dc:creator | dc:subject | dc:description | dc:publisher | dc:contributor | dc:date | dc:type | dc:format | dc:identifier | dc:source | dc:language | dc:relation | dc:coverage | dc:rights)*>
<!ATTLIST metadata xmlns:dc CDATA #FIXED "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> 
<!ELEMENT dc:title (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:creator (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:subject (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:description (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:publisher (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:contributor (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:date (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:type (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:format (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:identifier (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:source (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:language (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:relation (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:coverage (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT dc:rights (#PCDATA) >

<!ELEMENT frontmatter (%frontmatter;) >
<!ATTLIST frontmatter class CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT titlepage %titleinfo;>
<!ELEMENT body (part | chapter | subchapter | paragraph | poem | note)* >
<!ELEMENT part (frontmatter?, body, end?, note*)>
<!ELEMENT chapter ((frontmatter? | chapterfrontmatter?), body, end?, note*)>
<!ELEMENT subchapter (paragraph | note)*>

<!ELEMENT paragraph (#PCDATA  | poem | reference | emp | ital | quote | html:span)*>
<!ATTLIST paragraph class CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT html:span (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST html:span style CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT poem (line)*>
<!ELEMENT line (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT emp (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ital (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT quote (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT reference (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST reference     type    (footnote-num | footnote-ref)   #REQUIRED
                        ref     ID                              #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT note (paragraph*)>
<!ATTLIST note      class   CDATA   #REQUIRED
                    id      IDREF   #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT end (appendix | bibliography | endnotes | glossary | index | note )*>
```

Here is XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="SR-SciFi.css"?>
<!DOCTYPE book SYSTEM "book.dtd">
<!-- Use html:span for display using CSS -->
<!-- We can ignore all html:span elements if we use the same doc with XSLT -->
<book xmlns="http://www.steverenko.hostfree.pw/729/" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
        <dc:title>The Time Machine</dc:title>
        <dc:creator>Wells, H. G. (Herbert George), 1866-1946 </dc:creator>
        <dc:subject>Science fiction</dc:subject>
        <dc:subject>PR</dc:subject>
        <dc:language>eng</dc:language>
        <dc:description> </dc:description>
        <dc:publisher> www.kwongbor.net</dc:publisher>
        <dc:date>2019-07-15</dc:date>
        <dc:type>World Wide Web resource</dc:type>
        <dc:type>electronic resource</dc:type>
        <dc:type>text/xml</dc:type>
        <dc:identifier></dc:identifier>
        <dc:source>http://www.steverenko.hostfree.pw/729/</dc:source>
        <dc:relation>K.B.Ng's GSLIS 729</dc:relation>
        <dc:relation>Browser with XML parser</dc:relation>
        <dc:relation>Mode of access: Internet via World Wide Web</dc:relation>
        <dc:coverage> </dc:coverage>
        <dc:rights>The only legal and authorized use of these files is for the nonprofit production. 
                    The copyright for these files is the sole property of the original owner.  </dc:rights>
        <dc:rights>Access limited to students of GSLIS 729.</dc:rights>
    </metadata>
    <frontmatter>
        <html:img src="timemachinebookcover.jpg" style="float: left;"/>
        <titlepage>
            <title class="book"><html:a href= "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._G._Wells" target="_blank">
   The Time Machine</html:a>
  </title>
            <author>
                <firstname> Herbert </firstname>
                <middlename> George </middlename>
                <lastname> Wells </lastname>
                <html:a href="HGWellsCat.v03.xml">

                <html:img src="HGWells1922.small.gif" alt="Click to see our catalog of books written by the same author." style="margin-left: 20px;"/>
                </html:a>
            </author>
            <date> 1895 </date>
        </titlepage>
    </frontmatter>
    <body>
        <chapter>
            <frontmatter class="chapter">
                <titlepage>
                    <title class="chapter"> I </title>
                </titlepage>
            </frontmatter>
```

"The Time Machine" title element should be a hyperlink to the Wiki page referenced.

Currently, I get 
    "57:    37  A ')' is required in the declaration of element type "frontmatter".

I believe the line

```
  <title class="book"><html:a href= "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._G._Wells" target="_blank">
   The Time Machine</html:a>
  </title>
```

is what's throwing the whole thing off, but I can't figure out how to allow html:a within title element while conformning the DTD above

Comment: Could you highlight the specific line of code that is causing the problem please?

Comment: Added to the end, hopefully that helps!

Comment: The error is actually about the DTD; not the XML. It's complaining about the declaration for `frontmatter`. I see that the declaration for frontmatter is referencing a parameter entity (`%frontmatter;`). Are you sure you're validating with an external DTD? That error sounds like you have the DTD and XML combined (with the DTD in the internal subset). Parameter entity references can't be used in markup declarations in the internal subset ([see "Well-formedness constraint: PEs in Internal Subset" here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dtd)).

Comment: Also, is that the full DTD? You're missing 16 other element declarations. (Here's the list of elements missing element declarations: translator, subtitle, tableofcontents, preface, listoffigures, frontispiece, foreword, errata, dedication, acknowledgment, index, glossary, endnotes, bibliography, appendix, chapterfrontmatter)

Comment: It is the full DTD, I believe they’re missing because they’re not actually used in the XML. The original file Hs a hyperlink in an image in author element and I need to move it to the title element and still have it conform to DTD. I’m very new to this, and totally confused how to do that.